# Get cursor to jump briefly to open paren when I type close paren

Tags: osx, text-editing, cursor

Emacs on my computer at work behaves in the following way: When I type a close paren, the cursor briefly jumps to the matching open paren. I like this behavior, but I can't get Emacs on my Mac at home to do this. Here's what I've tried:

1. Disable the `smartparens` package.
2. Remove `(show-parens-mode 1)` from init.el.
3. Set `blink-matching-paren` to 'jump'.
4. Tried the following function suggested by the Emacs manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Blinking.html):

```
(defun interactive-blink-matching-open ()
  "Indicate momentarily the start of parenthesized sexp before point."
  (interactive)
  (let ((blink-matching-paren-distance
         (buffer-size))
        (blink-matching-paren t))
    (blink-matching-open)))
```

Nothing seems to work. This is GNU Emacs 28.1 running on MacOS 12.5 with an M1 CPU. I got Emacs from [emacsformacos.com](https://emacsformacos.com).

Thanks

Comment: It's called `show-paren-mode` (note the singular `paren`)  and it seems to be turned on by default. Make sure it is *not* enabled in the buffer of interest with e.g `M-: (show-paren-mode -1) RET`. You can *customize* the variable `show-paren-mode` and set it to `nil` to make it go away permanently. See its doc string with `C-h v show-paren-mode`. BTW, you don't need 4.

Comment: Thanks. This is somewhat embarrassing: It actually was working. Some time ago I had set the `show-paren-match` background to be less obtrusive. It turns out I went too far in the other direction. I had to look closely to see the flickering of the open paren. Fixed now.